# Apple ResearchKit: how to extract information from ORKResult? First time programmer

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, researchkit

I'm working on a simple ResearchKit app that has 20 survey questions, or ORKSteps. How do I get the answers from a participant who submits the survey into a database?

My research has found ORKESerializer and SQLite as potential parts of the solution. I'm missing a big picture view of how these things can be integrated into a working solution.

Starting without knowledge of databases or data transfer from Swift, so any basic information would be very helpful.

1. How do I extract data from ORKResult using Swift?
2. Where do I extract the data to? Or, what's the standard type of database for a small survey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ResearchKit* doesn't have any out-of-the-box solution for storing your results. Generally, it's the task of the developer to go through the `ORKResult` hierarchy and either persist the processed results for later access or send them to a remote server.

You have several options here:

- Use [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/) to store the vanilla `ORKTaskResult` (with their `ORKResult` children). This way you can recreate the whole `ORKTaskResult` hierarchy at later time to inspect or process it.
- Use `ORKESerializer` (as you guessed) to serialize `ORKResult`s into the *JSON* format. `ORKESerializer` is currently included as part of `ORKTest`'s unit tests, and it's not documented very well. It's possible that it will be moved to *ResearchKit* proper in the future, but it's completely usable right now. The *JSON* format is particularly useful if you want to send your results to any remote server of your own.
- You can manually iterate through `ORKResult`s and convert them into objects that are suitable for storing, or into database records. As you said, you could persist them using *SQLite*; or other database of your choice; or [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

To sum up, there's no recommended or standard method for persisting results, it depends on your needs.

You can also have a look at the official [open sourced RK apps](https://github.com/ResearchKit). I think they make use of the *AppCore* library (which sits on top of the *ResearchKit*) to store the task results (and also use the *Sage Bridge* to send the results to *Sage*'s servers). But that may be overboard if your needs are simpler.

---

I suggest that you run the sample `ORKCatalog` app and then inspect the `ORKTaskResult` hierarchy (you can do that within the app itself). You'll get an idea of how the result hierarchy looks.

Comment: yes ORKResults is completely different from storage, we can use it as we like.

Answer (score -2):

I do not have experience with the Research Kit but as a database you could use sqlite. [stephencelis](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) has made a great wrapper for swift which you can use.